# Bluetooth Obex using brecham.obex upload and download of folder

Tags: c#, obex

I have seen many samples how to upload and download files using the brecham.obex and I was able to do that, but my question is, using the brecham.obex, can I upload or download a folder instead of files only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to list the files in the folder/folders and up-/download each individually.  There are no other features in OBEX for this.

Comment: is it possible to unzip files on the server side? I'm planning to zip the folder and then unzip it after uploading it, vice versa zip the the file then download it then unzip.